# Arduino noise level indicator drifting from narrow optimum

Tags: arduino

My wife is always complaining about how loud I talk on my Teams calls and Xbox mic so I built a simple noise level indicator using an Arduino nano and a KY-037 sound sensor. It's simple but it works and a blue LED illuminates when my voice level gets too loud.
The trouble I have is the pot on the sound sensor is very difficult to get right as the optimum level is very narrow. This easily drifts during the day so I have to constantly adjust pot.
Is there a way to increase that narrow window?

[image: Fritzing layout]
[image: KY-037 Sound Sensor]

```
void setup() {
  //here is an input for sound sensor
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);
  //here we are setting up all pins as an outputs for LEDs
  for(int z = 2; z < 12; z++){
    pinMode(z, OUTPUT);
  }
}
void loop() {
  //here we are storing the volume value
  int volume = analogRead(A0);
  //max value for analog read is 1023 but it must be very very loud to reach this value
  //so I lower it down in map function to 700
  //mapping volume value to make it easier to turn LEDs on
  volume = map(volume, 0, 700, 2, 12);
    if(volume >= 11){
      //if it is bigger we can turn on the LED
      digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
    }else{
      //if it is smaller we can turn the LED off
      digitalWrite(11, LOW);
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a problem with accessing the potentiometer you can add another one to change the threshold. If you add it to pin A1 you could just change this line:

```
volume = map(volume, 0, analogRead(A1), 2, 12);
```

Adding a moving average filter might also make to sensor more reliable,
here is a tutorial on it: https://maker.pro/arduino/tutorial/how-to-clean-up-noisy-sensor-data-with-a-moving-average-filter